# SSAS - Dimension and Fact tables historical data - Mapping fact table with dimension table

Tags: ssas, data-warehouse, dimension, fact

i have designed places related warehouse tables - DimPlaces, FactPlaces, DimGeography. It is straightforward design if you see. All the locations is in DimPlaces (Addrline1, Addrline2,placename,etc) and geography hierarchy is in DimGeography (City, State, Country, PostCode). FactPlaces is table which has got foriegn keys to DimPlaces and DimGeography.

I would like to maintain historical data as there are chances that places names or their properties might change and at the same time if the location of a place changes then geographic hierarchy key changes.

I have found design pattern -

Another useful design pattern is to add the durable account key to the fact table in addition to the dimension’s surrogate key. This joins back to the current rows in the dimension to make it easier to report all of history by the current dimension attributes.

Could you please suggest is this OK to follow this solution? If yes, do i need to use KEY of type UNIQUEIDENTIFIER for a unique value?

Another question on this - I have employees data (DimEmployee and FactEmployee). Each employee is associated with the places where he works. How to connect These EMPLOYEE TABLES with the PLACES TABLES. Do I need to connect FACTEMPLOYEE WITH FACTPLACES?

Answer (score 0):

I think in the first instance, they're referring to business keys? So if your dimension table has two rows, surrogate key 1 & 2, but they both refer to the same thing, so both have AccountId/ProductId/WhateverId of 1, then you will have some fact table rows with surrogate key 1 and business key 1, and later ones with surrogate key 2 and business key 1.

Uniqueidentifiers are very wide, try and avoid using them on fact tables and for joins if possible.

For your last question - That's really more a reporting thing. Do you need to do that? Is that what people need to see, do they need to slice by that? You could consider a referenced dimension - Where the places table links to the fact tables via a placeId on the employees dimension. Or, you could have a factemployees table with start and stop dates. It depends on what you need to achieve.

Comment: Thanks Meff, I agree uniqueidentifiers are very wide, could you please suggest what is the other way to get unique id in the businesskey column other than identity column. I am struggling on that.

Comment: @ChrisChris, the dimension has a surrogate key, this is an identity on the dimension table. The business key is the identity from the source table, so if your table is DimProduct, then the business key is probably the Identity column of the Product table in the source database. Does your dimension table source not have a primary key?